# Azure and Single sign on approache

Tags: azure, single-sign-on, saas

I need to extend our SSO implementation so that it could also cover our applications when it is installed on Azure as a SaaS. I am going through the documentation, but as always I am getting confused. 
What I am trying to find is a way for our application (the server is written in C) to use Azure to check if the user credentials sent from the client is correct. 
could someone provide some web pages that can explain the issue?

cheers.
es

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are new to authentication and Azure AD then, in my opinion, you should start by familiarizing yourself with the modern authentication flows that OAuth 2.0 offers.

### Authorization flows

To mention a few of the most common flows:

- **Client credentials Grant**

  - No end-user authorization is required?
  - The client does a machine to machine authorization. E.g. cron job or scheduled task
- **Authorization Code Grant**

  - Web app requiring user to authorize
  - Considered the safest option since token is passed directly to back-end
- **Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant**

  - Considered a very unsafe alternative, only to be used when noting else is suited
  - Credentials are sent in a POST request to the authorization server
- **Implicit Grant**

  - Mostly used in single-page-applications (SPA's)
  - Token is sent directly to the clients browser
- **Device Code**

  - Relatively new compared to previous flows
  - Suited for scenarios where direct user interaction with the application is difficult, e.g. IoT application or smart tv applications (imagine writing a 24 character password with your tv remote...)
  - Login URL and code is passed to the user and user signs in on a desktop using provided information
  - Initiating application keep polling service until timeout or authenticated
  - Once logged on using desktop, initiating application is logged on

Being familiar with these will help you identify their use cases and limitations.

### Single sign-on

You are mentioning you need SSO for you application, in such case I recommend you familiarize yourself with the **Authorization Code Grant** and **Implicit Grant** flows. These are the most common flows you find used in websites that requiring the user to sign-in.

SSO will work assuming:

- In the same Azure AD
- Opened in the same browser
- User has logged on to either app

  - The authentication cookie must be present and readable
- Consented to the app (either admin or user)

### Further reading

Have a look at these pages for more information on how to choose the right flow and how to implement them:

- [Which OAuth 2.0 flow should I use?](https://auth0.com/docs/api-auth/which-oauth-flow-to-use)
- [Authentication Scenarios for Azure AD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-authentication-scenarios)
- [Azure Active Directory Code Samples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-code-samples)

Also, if you really get excited about Azure AD authentication, then there's a quite good book, written by Vittorio Bertocci that's worth checking out:

- [Modern Authentication with Azure Active Directory for Web Applications](https://www.microsoftpressstore.com/store/modern-authentication-with-azure-active-directory-for-9780735698468).

Vittorio Bertocci is a Principal Program Manager at Microsoft and really knowledgeable on this topic.